# insert string into List<int>

Tags: c#, string, list, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse string to int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050910/parse-string-to-int-array)

I have string which comes from a numeric `textbox` like this: `2670053157`. how should I split each character of string and insert them into `List<int>` elements?

Answer (score 6):

```
var list = numberString.Select(c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString())).ToList();
```

Or, if you'd rather add to an existing list:

```
list.AddRange(numberString.Select(c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var list = new List<int>();

list.AddRange(
    from character in numericString
    select int.Parse(character));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 List<int> numericlist = "2670053157".Select(c => c - '0').ToList();
```

Comment: What did you do there? `c - '0'`

Comment: @Silvermind - Chars are ints. Subracting '0' (48) from '2' (50) would result in 2.

Comment: The only reason I wouldn't suggest doing it this way is because it won't properly handle the case where there is a non-numeric character in the string.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Thanks, Learned some new logic today.

Comment: @JustinNiessner it would be good in cases where exception is not wanted (Int.Parse would throw exception and Int.TryParse does not suit well to linq)

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of exceptions being thrown due to improper inputs, you could always go the safe route:

```
// string input = TextBox1.Text;
List<int> intList = new List<int>();

foreach (char c in input)
{
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(c.ToString(), out i))
    {
        intList.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start out with a helper method:

```
public static IEnumerable<short> getDigits(long input)
{
    while (input > 0)
    {
        yield return (short)(input % 10);
        input /= 10;
    }
}
```

Then if you want the values in a list, just call `ToList`:

```
List<short> list = getDigits(2670053157).ToList();
```

If you want the higher order bits first you'll need to `Reverse` the sequence:

```
List<short> list = getDigits(2670053157).Reverse().ToList();
```